How to pass an instance of an object called via QQmlComponent::create to an existing QML element in the layout tree
I am in the process of developing a GUI, and during the development process there was a need to pass a dynamically created element into an existing Qml layout.
I am using the following method to gen the element:
QQuickItem *AbstractContent::createFromSource(const QString &source, const QString &objectName)
{
    Q_ASSERT_X(engine != nullptr, "init", "ContentHandler FATAL ERROR: QQmlApplicationEngine not inizialised");

    QQmlComponent component(engine, QUrl::fromLocalFile(source));
    QQuickItem *contentItem = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(component.create());

    contentItem->setObjectName(objectName);

    return contentItem;
}

Next, I'm trying to move the item into the tree of already existing items:
auto rootItems = engine->rootObjects();
QObject* contentRect;

if( auto mainWin = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(rootItems.at(0)) )
{
    contentRect = mainWin->findChild<QObject*>("ContentItem");
}

createFromSource("qmlitem.qml", "objectname")->setParent(contentRect );

However, trivial assignment of the parent does not make the instance move into the qml tree.
What methods should produce the desired result?

This could be an interesting reading for this topic: https://www.kdab.com/recursive-instantiation-with-qt-quick-and-json/. It describes a configuration framework building layouts from JSON files dynamically.

Does it work if you use setParentItem instead of setParent?

For loose coupling, you should do nothing more than populate a model, such as QAbstractItemModel from C++, and, in QML, you should consume that model in a Repeater, ListView, or equivalent. QML will take care of the dynamic construction and cleanup of your delegates.

Thank you JarMan! I came to that decision, too, after a couple of minutes

There is a common confusion. QObjects have a property called parent, and so do Items within QML code. But they don't mean the same thing. An Item's parent property is sometimes called the visual parent as opposed to the "object parent". Its underlying C++ code in QQuickItem calls it the parentItem. Since you are attempting to add a QML item to the visual hierarchy, you should be calling setParentItem() instead of setParent().
